System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' error en crystal report
Estoy aprendiendo a usar crystal reports y al momento de crear el reporte me sale ese del título cuanto intento hacer el filtrado error este es mi código
private void btnFiltrar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fechaInicio = dpFechaInicio.SelectedDate.Value;
    DateTime fechaFin = dpFechaFin.SelectedDate.Value;

    try
    {
        Venta_ClienteImpl venta_ClienteImpl = new Venta_ClienteImpl();
        DataSet dataSet = venta_ClienteImpl.GetVenta_Clientes(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Reporte1 reporte1 = new Reporte1();
            reporte1.SetDataSource(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            frmReporte frmReporte = new frmReporte();
            frmReporte.crystalReport1.ReportSource = reporte1;
            frmReporte.Show();


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) ;
    }

    
}


No uses el mismo nombre para la variable y para la clase

Ya lo cambie y sigue con el mismo error

El problema está en tu clase frmReporte. Esta no instancia correctamente crystalReport1, de modo que es indefinido para el momento en que se ejecuta. Si puedes pasa el código de tu clase y será más claro el problema.

Revisar [answer]. saludos.
